# Integer Type in Form - Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a FormType.php builder made with symfony 3.2 (while using PhpStorm.2016.3.2)

There is a field where there is the need to put a number into the form.

```
->add('authorPhone', NumberType::class, array('label' => 'Numéro de téléphone',
    'required' => true,
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'validate',
        'id' => 'icon_telephone'
    )
))
```

I need to actually add only numeric values, and my questions is, how to do that with `annotations` ?

I know that I should add `type="integer"`, but I don't know if that is possible in the first place.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Regex validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html).

With annotation, it would be something like that :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

/**/

/**
 * @Regex("[(\d) ]*")
 */
protected $authorPhone;
```

And in PHP :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

/**/

->add('authorPhone', NumberType::class, array('label' => 'Numéro de téléphone',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'validate',
                'id' => 'icon_telephone'
            ),
            'constraints' => array(new Regex("[(\d) ]*"))
        ))
```

`[(\d) ]*` allows numerics and white spaces.

Comment: Is there a possibility to add a error message too? if its filled with letters? (because actually with your constraints I still can add letters, is this normal?) @versgui

Comment: Actually, if you use my regexp, you should use TextType. If not, juste use this regexp : (\d)* (decimals only). For error message, check the [invalid_message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#invalid-message) parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I done that, I added a invalid_message parameter. But I tried to render it in my view using twig, but couldn't have any message when I filled the form and submitted it. How can I actually make this working?